# Count the word frequency per class

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a vectorized dataframe:

```
aeriforms   æronaut æschylus    æstheticus  écarte  échapper    élite   été être    classification
    Adventure
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Parody
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0       Humor
    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Adventure,Science_fiction
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   Horror

    0   0   0   0   7   0   0   2   0   Fiction,Hoax
    0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   Detective_fiction
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Essay
    0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   Hoax,Science_fiction
    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   Satire
```

I did the following to have the frequency of each word in all the documents.
`vectorizer.vocabulary_`
which gives me the following:

```
{'the': 17480,
 'ways': 19180,
 'of': 12049,
 'god': 7830,
 'in': 9000,
 'nature': 11611,
 'as': 1167,
 'providence': 13811,
 'are': 1064,
 'not': 11838,
 'our': 12259,
 'nor': 11816,
 'models': 11231,
 'that': 17477,
...}
```

But how can I have the frequency of each per `classification`? I am rather new to that so I am a bit stuck, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function in python, to add all values in a row.

Comment: How do you use that?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-2d-array-python-using-map-function/